# Ransack with collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Afternoon,

I'm finding Ransack a little confusing. I'm trying to populate my dropdown with only the values available and filter the index based on that but when I try with various options it pulls all the information into the dropdown including duplicates.

How can I create this form so that it shows only what is available and does the search based on that.

jobs_controller.rb

```
 def index
    @jobs = Job.all
    @show_sub_nav = true
    @q = Job.search(params[:q])
    @searches = @q.result(distinct: true)
    @lang = Job.find_by_sql("SELECT languages FROM jobs GROUP BY languages").map &:languages
end
```

_subnav.html.erb

```
  <%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
     <%= f.select "languages", options_for_select(@lang) %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

I currently get this error:

> No valid predicate for languages

Thanks for the help, I have real trouble trying to understand collection_select and these form_helpers as I don't find the API documentation very helpful so any links would be useful as well.

Comment: Why the `find_by_sql`? Can't you use `Job.has_many :languages`? If you use that, then maybe `options_for_select` will find the kind of query result it can use.

Comment: You can use that .has_many in a controller, I thought that was only for datatbase relationships, languages is a field column not a model.

Comment: and `p @lang` shows a one-dimensional array of strings?

Comment: Yes @lang is designed just to show the items in the array for the dropdown, which works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ransack, you need to add a predicate onto the field name.  If you want to do an exact match against the option that is chosen you can do something like:

```
<%= f.select :language_eq, @lang %>
```

For more on predicates, see the [Basic Searching](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching) page.  Additional info is available in [RailsCast 370](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack).